# MySQL query - unknown column

Tags: mysql, field, alias

I'm trying to run a query, but I get an "unknown column 'MyField' in 'where clause'" error.

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, sum(lineValue * quantity) as TotalLine
FROM myTable
WHERE (TotalLine BETWEEN 10 and 500)
group by id
```

How can I perform a similar query?
Thanks

Comment: added group by statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, SUM(lineValue * quantity) as TotalLine
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY
        id
HAVING  TotalLine BETWEEN 10 and 500
```